# In Azure DevOps I cannot add a User to my Team

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

We have a DevOps project we've been using for over a year now and we needed to add a new developer to the team.  I was able to add the user to the organization, he replied to the invite, and I have added him to the contributor group.

After adding him I then went to my project and opened up that project's Team Settings.  When I click Add and try to find his name I am getting a spinning status graphic and "Loading..." but it does not find the user.  It does not give me an error or a "No Results Found". Eventually it just resets back as though I first landed on the page.

[image: Azure Error: Add User to Team]

I thought this could be a permissions issue so I removed an existing user in the group.  Right after removing I tried to re-add the user and cannot.  I get the same results. I know this user is using the project and has permission to get the code and check in changes.  So it does not seem to be an issue with the original new user.

My next move was to try to do this using the Azure CLI but it turns out that adding a user to a project is not currently supported by the CLI, only adding the user to the organization is currently supported.  I also searched for this particular error and can't find anyone else having this issue.

Comment: Could you try these troubleshootings, Go the **Preview features**  and disable **New Teams Page** and try again? Or re-add the user to your Organization and try again?

Comment: This was such a weird issue.  It seems like it is a bug in the portal.  I could not add the users here.  However, if I went to the Dashboard and used the Team Users widget instead, it added without any problem at all.  So if you can't add a user here on the Teams page try the widget on the dashboard.

Comment: That is great you found the fix. You can post above fix  as answer and mark it.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I had the same issue today and it worked after disabling the New Teams Page feature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a [[[bug]]] in the Azure portal.  Users could not be added from the Team page.  However, I had a widget on my dashboard for Users and it had the ability to add a User.  When I used this widget I was able to add users.  I could add the ones I deleted during testing and the new user.

Comment: Thanks Larry. I added 'Team Members' widget in dashboard and added users from the widget.

Comment: Amazing solution! They do really poorly with those bugs...

Comment: I ran into the _exact_ same thing today, which has _never_ happened in the last five years. Thanks for this!!

Comment: This still works as a workaround for me in 2024.